# How to map docker container address to custom 'redis://redis:6379' host?

Tags: docker, redis

I am writing a celery application which needs to connect to redis at the host:
`redis://redis:6379` - it has to be this specific has because of the way my other apps are connecting to redis.

I do the following:

```
# Install redis from docker hub
docker run -name redis -d redis
```

Then bind to local port:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 redis
```

I know how to map it to `localhost:6379` but how do i map it to the host `redis://redis:6379`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry to your `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 redis
```

That's it, now hostname `redis` is resolved to the loopback address. Then you expose the port as usual:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 redis
```

Comment: @treedust: I rejected your edit. I most certainly did mean 127.0.0.1.